# aws cdk nextjs graphql mutation cannot return null for non-nullable type after adding in new schema field

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql, aws-cdk

I have tried to modify the schema to add a ingredients String line. From this code
I am pretty much following it to a tee https://github.com/dabit3/next.js-cdk-amplify-workshop
you can look in the backend and frontend folders to see all the code

I have built and deployed with cdk

My error is at the bottom

Any help would be great

Here's the relevant parts of the schema in the backend

```
# graphql/schema.graphql
type Post @aws_api_key @aws_cognito_user_pools {
  id: ID!
  title: String!
  content: String!
  ingredients: String!
  owner: String!
}

input PostInput {
  id: ID
  title: String!
  ingredients: String!
  content: String!
}

input UpdatePostInput {
  id: ID!
  title: String
  content: String
  ingredients: String
}
```

Here is my graphql.js in my frontend code

```
export const getPostById = /* GraphQL */ `
  query getPostById($postId: ID!) {
    getPostById(postId: $postId) {
      id
      title
      content
      ingredients
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const listPosts = /* GraphQL */ `
  query ListPosts {
    listPosts {
      id
      title
      content
      ingredients
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const postsByUsername = /* GraphQL */ `
  query PostsByUsername {
    postsByUsername {
      id
      title
      content
      ingredients
      owner
    }
  }
`;

export const createPost = /* GraphQL */ `
  mutation CreatePost($post: PostInput!) {
    createPost(post: $post) {
      id
      title
      content
      ingredients
      owner
    }
  }
`;
```

Then I have tried the following in the create-post.js in my frontend

```
// pages/create-post.js
import { withAuthenticator } from "@aws-amplify/ui-react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { API } from "aws-amplify";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import SimpleMDE from "react-simplemde-editor";
import "easymde/dist/easymde.min.css";
import { createPost } from "../graphql";

const initialState = { title: "", content: "", ingredients: "" };

function CreatePost() {
  const [post, setPost] = useState(initialState);
  const { title, content, ingredients } = post;
  const router = useRouter();
  function onChange(e) {
    setPost(() => ({ ...post, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  }
  async function createNewPost() {
    if (!title || !content || !ingredients) return;
    const id = uuid();
    post.id = id;

    await API.graphql({
      query: createPost,
      variables: { post },
      authMode: "AMAZON_COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
    });
    router.push(`/posts/${id}`);
  }
  return (
    <div style={containerStyle}>
      <h2>Create new Post</h2>
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        name="title"
        placeholder="Title"
        value={post.title}
        style={inputStyle}
      />
      <input
        onChange={onChange}
        name="ingredients"
        placeholder="Ingredients"
        value={post.ingredients}
        style={inputStyle}
      />
      <SimpleMDE
        value={post.content}
        onChange={(value) => setPost({ ...post, content: value })}
      />
      <button style={buttonStyle} onClick={createNewPost}>
        Create Post
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

const inputStyle = {
  marginBottom: 10,
  height: 35,
  width: 300,
  padding: 8,
  fontSize: 16,
};
const containerStyle = { padding: "0px 40px" };
const buttonStyle = {
  width: 300,
  backgroundColor: "white",
  border: "1px solid",
  height: 35,
  marginBottom: 20,
  cursor: "pointer",
};
export default withAuthenticator(CreatePost);
```

I then get the following message when trying to create the post

```
{
  type: 'Object',
  stack: null,
  data: { listPosts: [ [Object], null, [Object], null ] },
  errors: [
    {
      path: [Array],
      locations: null,
      message: "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'String' within parent 'Post' (/listPosts[1]/ingredients)"
    },
    {
      path: [Array],
      locations: null,
      message: "Cannot return null for non-nullable type: 'String' within parent 'Post' (/listPosts[3]/ingredients)"
    }
  ]
}
```

lambda-fns/listPosts.ts

```
// lambda-fns/listPosts.ts
const AWS = require('aws-sdk')
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient()

async function listPosts() {
    const params = {
        TableName: process.env.POST_TABLE,
    }
    try {
        const data = await docClient.scan(params).promise()
        return data.Items
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('DynamoDB error: ', err)
        return null
    }
}

export default listPosts
```

I was missing adding the ingredients in the Post.ts file in my backend

```
// lambda-fns/Post.ts
type Post = {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    content: string,
    ingredients: string,
    owner: string
}

export default Post
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like there are some debugging details missing from your question.  For example, your error message displays the results of a `listPosts` query, but you don't show that being called anywhere.  Also, that query apparently returns something, so it would be good to see the database entries backing it.

If I had to guess, you have entries in your dynamo table that have missing `ingredients` fields, which is why you see an error: the query is trying to marshal missing/null fields to a return type of `String!`, which is by definition non-nullable.

Also, I'm not sure you should be setting `id` directly on your `post` state object.  Better to copy the object and set the property on the copy, esp since you're just using it as a parameter.